# Custom style for wordpress pagination

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, pagination

I have my custom pagination in html and i want to apply all of its css to my custom wordpress pagination.Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r56oseu0/) demo.

Can you please help me out with this.All I want to do is make the same [pagination](https://jsfiddle.net/r56oseu0/) for wordpress. Thanx guys.

Here is what I did until now:

```
<section class="pager m-50">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <?php
                global $wp_query;
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                $links = paginate_links( array(
                    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text' => __('<div class="btn-gold pull-left">←</div>','multi'),
                    'next_text' => __('<div class="btn-gold pull-right">→</div>','multi'),
                    'type'      => 'array',
                ));
            ?>
            <?php if (count($links) > 0) : ?>
            <div class="archive-navigation">
                <?php foreach ($links as $link) : ?>
                <?php echo $link; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif ?><!-- End of blog-pagination -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And what I've done so far for wordpress styles is down here:

```
/*-- pager --*/
.pager a {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -ms-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s; 
    transition: all 0.1s;
} 
.pager a.page-numbers:hover {
    background: none;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #b3a06c;
}
span.page-numbers.current {
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #b3a06c;
}


/*-- pager --*/
div.btn-gold.pull-right {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;  
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
div.btn-gold.pull-right.next, div.btn-gold.pull-right.prev {    
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
div.btn-gold.pull-right.prev  {
    left: 0;
}
div.btn-gold.pull-right.next:hover {    
    right: 15px;
}
div.btn-gold.pull-right.prev {
    left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a pic of pagination which you want to get, I can't understand you well.

Comment: @ristapk  Here is the jsfiddle  link (https://jsfiddle.net/r56oseu0/). i want the exact thing in wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme have bootstrap included, then pagination is shown as below screenshot:

[image]

After overriding .pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span {border: none !important;} the pagination shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Let me know if there is still any confusion and please remove the -2 provided as this works flawlessly.

Comment: What you said works fine, but the main issue is that I need animation to be applied on arrows when I hover on them for wordpress. Check the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r56oseu0/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution.

Here's Pagination Code:

```
<section class="pager m-50">
    <div class="row">
            <div>
            <?php
                global $wp_query;
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                $pages = paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                        'prev_text' => '<div class="btn-gold pull-left">←</div>',
                        'next_text' => '<div class="btn-gold pull-right">→</div>',
                        'type'  => 'array',
                    ) );
            if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged'); ?>
                <ul class="pagination">
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $pages as $page ) { ?>
                            <li><?php echo $page; ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
               </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is Style Code:

```
/*-- pager --*/
.pager a.page-numbers:hover {
    background: none;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #b3a06c;
}
span.page-numbers.current {
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #b3a06c;
}
.pagination li {
        border: none;
}

.pagination li a {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        -moz-transition: all 0.1s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s; 
    transition: all 0.1s;
} 

.pagination li span {
        padding: 6px 12px;
}

.pager a {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;  
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.pager .btn-gold:nth-child(1) a {        
        right: 0;
                 -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.pager .btn-gold:nth-child(2) a , .pager .btn-gold:nth-child(3) a {
        left: 0;
}
.pager .btn-gold:nth-child(1):hover a {        
        right: 15px;
}
.pager .btn-gold:nth-child(2):hover a, .pager .btn-gold:nth-child(3):hover a {
        left: 15px;
}
.btn-gold {
        min-height: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b3a06c;
  background: none !important;
  color: #b3a06c;
   -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;  
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```